# cv2.bitwise_and: Operation is neither 'array op array'

Tags: python, opencv

I'm struggling to understand how I have contradicting sizes of arrays. I start with 'cv_image' to get to the canny_image of 1's and 0's:

```
    # Convert to Gray --> blur --> canny
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    k_width = 21 # 7
    k_height = 21 # 7
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_image, (k_width, k_height), 0)
    threshold_low = 40 # 40
    threshold_high = 20 # 20 
    canny_image = cv2.Canny(blurred, threshold_low, threshold_high)
    kernel = np.ones((7,7), dtype=np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.dilate(canny_image, kernel, iterations =2)
```

Followed by creating a region of Interest based on the 'cv_image' size:

```
    ## Region of Interest
    triangle = np.array([
        [(50, height), (590, height), (320, 200)]
        ])
    mask_roi = np.zeros_like(cv_image)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask_roi, triangle, 255)


    ## Masking Region of Interest
    masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(canny_image, mask_roi) 
    masked_image2 = cv2.bitwise_and(canny_image, mask_roi, mask= None) 
    masked_image3 = cv2.bitwise_and(canny_image, canny_image, mask = mask_roi)
```

Iterations masked_image2, masked_image3 were out of frustration. Can someone point out my mistake? I thought I have same array size and 1 channel...

```
 The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function binary_op
```

Comment: _I thought I have same array size and 1 channel..._ No, you don't have. Inspecting `mask_roi` at runtime shows you, that you have three channels. That's because of `mask_roi = np.zeros_like(cv_image)`, and `cv_image` is some three channel image. Fastest fix would to change that line to `mask_roi = np.zeros_like(gray_image)`.

Comment: You're right. Thank you for your help!